# extend volume of CentOS7 VM

Tags: vmware-esxi, centos7, lvm

There is an issabel VM which I increased the VM hard drive from 20G to 1.07T through ESXi.

Next I add sda4 partition as new Linux LVM (following [this path](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smb-technologist/extending-partitions-on-linux-vmware-virtual-machines/) at step 22 ), seems I have to use `vgextend [volume group] /dev/sda4` now but there is no Volume Group or at least `vgdisplay`,`vgs`,`dh -f` will show no `VG`.
here is the outputs:

fdisk -l:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1176.5 GB, 1176477441536 bytes, 2297807503 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000c90e0

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      616447      307200   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          616448     4810751     2097152   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3         4810752    41943039    18566144   83  Linux
/dev/sda4        41943040  2297807502  1127932231+  8e  Linux LVM
```

df -h :

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           2.0G  9.0M  2.0G   1% /run
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3        18G  3.3G   14G  21% /
/dev/sda1       283M  118M  147M  45% /boot
tmpfs           396M     0  396M   0% /run/user/0
```

pvdisplay:

```
 "/dev/sda4" is a new physical volume of "1.05 TiB"
      --- NEW Physical volume ---
      PV Name               /dev/sda4
      VG Name
      PV Size               1.05 TiB
      Allocatable           NO
      PE Size               0
      Total PE              0
      Free PE               0
      Allocated PE          0


vgdisplay:
vgs:
lvdisplay:
```

I changed sda4 from 83 to 8e.

What should i do to extend?

Comment: Correct, there is no LVM set up, so you can't use LVM to extend it. Delete sda4 and resize sda3 to the maximum size. Afterwards extend the filesystem accordingly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extending a partition on a VMware disk in Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/969086/extending-a-partition-on-a-vmware-disk-in-linux)

Comment: well, droped  sda4 and resized the sda3 to maximum , now i want to extend filesystem with xfs_growfs /dev/sda3 which says:/dev/sda3 is not a mounted XFS filesystem. can you help what should i do for this now

Comment: Is it actually XFS?

Comment: its finished with resize2fs /dev/sda3 . thanks for your guide :)